# How to mock SVG's when snapshot testing with vitest and Storybook?

Tags: testing, mocking, snapshot, storybook, vitest

I am trying to run vitest snapshot tests on Storybook stories using the composeStories Fn from @storybook/testing-react, but I keep getting the error:

```
FAIL  src/components/common/Nav/Nav.test.tsx > Nav Component > it should match the snapshot
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function
(for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Nav`.
//... stack trace
```

I believe it's related to the svg imports, as this only occurs in components that import svgs as react components via the SVGR library. i.e.

```
// components/common/Nav.tsx

import { ReactComponent as ECDLogo } from '@assets/ecd_logo.svg';
```

And my vite.config.ts uses the vite-svgr-plugin:

```
// vite.config.ts

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import path from 'path';

const tsConfigPathsOpts = {
  extensions: ['.svg', '.png', '.jpeg'],
  loose: true,
};

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
  },
  define: {
    global: {},
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets'),
      '@styles': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles'),
      '@types': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/types'),
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [react(), svgr(), tsconfigPaths(tsConfigPathsOpts)],
});
```

My Storybook config (.storybook/main.js) looks like so:

```
const path = require('path');
const { mergeConfig } = require('vite');
const tsconfigPaths = require('vite-tsconfig-paths');
const svgr = require('vite-plugin-svgr');

const tsConfigPathsOpts = {
  extensions: ['.svg', '.png', '.jpeg'],
  loose: true,
};


module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
    '@storybook/addon-a11y',
    '@storybook/node-logger',
    'storybook-addon-designs',
    'storybook-color-picker',
    'storybook-dark-mode',
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-vite',
  },
  async viteFinal(config, { configType }) {
    return mergeConfig(config, {
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
          '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
          '@styles': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles'),
          '@types': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/types'),
          '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components'),
        },
      },
      plugins: [svgr(), tsconfigPaths.default(tsConfigPathsOpts)],
    });
  },
};
```

I've come to understand that I need to mock these SVG's so that their snapshot is consistent, but I need direction on whether my mocking implementation is correct. See the vi.mock Fn below.

```
// components/common/Nav/Nav.test.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { composeStories } from '@storybook/testing-react';
import * as stories from './Nav.stories'; // import all stories from the stories file
import { vi } from 'vitest';

const { NavDefault } = composeStories(stories);


vi.mock('@assets/*', () => {
  return {
    default: 'SVGUrl',
    ReactComponent: 'div',
  };
});

describe('Nav Component', () => {
  test('it should match the snapshot', () => {
    const { asFragment } = render(<NavDefault />);
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

I was expecting this to mock all the imports from @assets/* to be strings "SVGUrl" or 'div'

But I get the same error as above:

```
FAIL  src/components/common/Nav/Nav.test.tsx > Nav Component > it should match the snapshot
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Answer (score 2):

we had the same issue today and fixed it by adding the plugin `svgr()` in `vitest.config.ts`

```
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    // ...other plugins
    svgr(),
  ]
})
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the response. I have svgr() listed as a plugin in my Vite.config.ts and am still experiencing the issue. Ultimately, we removed the snapshot tests as they were causing more headache then good.

Comment: hey, just a heads up, I mean on the viTEST.config.ts, not just vite.config.ts !

Comment: Does not work, added this plugin to vitest.config

Comment: worked for me. Might be worth noting that I have svgo: false in my next.config